# prolog two lists are exactly the same

Tags: list, prolog

I want to write a function that returns true if two lists are exactly the same(order of elements matters).

I tried it this way:

```
same([ ], [ ]).   
same([H1|R1], [H2|R2]):-
    H1 == H2,
    same(R1, R2).
```

It returns true while two lists are the same, also I expect if I have

```
?- same(X, [1, 2, 3]).
```

I want it to return

```
X = [1, 2, 3].
```

But it doesn't work if input is like this. Here are some sample outputs I got:

```
?- same([1, 2], [1, 2]).

true.

?- same([2, 1], [1, 2]).

false.

?- same(X, [1, 2, 3]).

false.

?- same([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, X]).

false.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `==/2` (checking whether two items are instantiated the same) rather than `=/2` (checks if two items are unified or unifiable). Just change to unification:

```
same([], []).

same([H1|R1], [H2|R2]):-
    H1 = H2,
    same(R1, R2).
```

Then this will have the behavior you're looking for:

```
| ?- same(X, [1, 2, 3]).

X = [1,2,3] ? a

no
| ?- same([1, 2], [1, 2]).

(1 ms) yes
| ?- same([2, 1], [1, 2]).

no
| ?- same([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, X]).

X = 3

(1 ms) yes
| ?- same([A,B,C], L).

L = [A,B,C]

yes
% In this last example, A, B, and C are variables. So it says L is [A,B,C],
% whatever A, B, and C are.
```

If you query `X == 3` in Prolog, and `X` is not bound to the value `3`, or it is just unbound, it will fail. If `X` is unbound and you query, `X = 3`, then Prolog will unify `X` (bind it) with `3` and it will succeed.

For more regarding the difference between `=/2` and `==/2`, see [What is the difference between == and = in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219555/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-prolog)

You can also use `maplist` for a nice, compact solution. `maplist` is very handy for iterating through a list:

```
same(L1, L2) :- maplist(=, L1, L2).
```

Here, unification (`=/2`) is still used for exactly the same reason as above.

---

Finally, as @Boris points out, in Prolog, the unification predicate will work on entire lists. In this case, this would suffice:

```
same(L1, L2) :- L1 = L2.
```

Or equivalently:

```
same(L, L).  % Would unify L1 and L2 queried as same(L1, L2)
```

This will succeed if the lists are the same, or will attempt to unify them by unifying each element in turn.

```
| ?- same([1,2,X], [1,2,3]).    % Or just [1,2,X] = [1,2,3]

X = 3

yes
| ?- same([1,2,X], [1,2,3,4]).  % Or just [1,2,X] = [1,2,3,4]

no
```

The prior more elaborate approaches are considered an exercise in list processing for illustration. But the simplest and most correct method for comparison and/or unification of lists would be `L1 = L2`.

Comment: This answer is strange (as is the original question). Why are you not directly unifying the two lists?

Comment: @Boris the question isn't strange if you consider that it is an exercise in list processing. But you're right about the answer. I lost sight of the simplest approach as I provided an answer following that of illustrating list processing. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: And actually, same(X, X). is enough, but this is infact =(X, X).

Comment: how would you do this if you didn't care about order?

Comment: @hiswendy the simplest thing to do would be to use `msort` to put them in order and not remove duplicates, then just attempt to unify them afterwards. So, `same(L1, L2) :- msort(L1, S1), msort(L2, S2), S1 = S2.` A longer way, but less imperative, would be to go element by element and use `select/3`.