# Prolog, unknown argument solving

Tags: variables, prolog

I have a question about my rule. It should return true if Var1 and Var2 are first elements in two given lists.

It works okay here:

```
?- testpos([test1, test2, test3], [testA, testB, testC], test1, testA).
true.

?- testpos([test1, test2, test3], [testA, testB, testC], test1, testB).
false.
```

But I want the rule be able to solve it for unkown input.

For example(expected output):

```
?- testpos([test1, test2, test3], [testA, testB, testC], Z, X).
Z = test1
X = testA
false.
```

My code now:

```
testpos([X| _], [Y| _], Var1, Var2) :-
    X == Var1, Y == Var2.
```

**Solved**

My mistake was that I used == instead of =

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there

```
testpos([X| _], [Y| _], Var1, Var2) :-
    X = Var1, Y = Var2.
```

`==/2` succeeds when both it's arguments are equivalent without further unification, where as `=/2` succeeds when they are unifiable and the arguments are unified.

Look at this answer: [What is the difference between == and = in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219555/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-prolog)

You can just as well write:

```
testpos([X| _], [Y| _], X, Y).
```

Prolog does unification to match the clause, so they are essentially equivalent.